# Filter list using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, filter

I have a JS code that filters the list with an input field. Currently, the filter is a case sensitive. For example, if you have "item1" you have to type the exact word to filter.

```
$(function(){

    $('input.search').keyup(function(){

        var searchText = $(this).val();

        $('ul.tabs-menu > li').each(function(){

            var currentLiText = $(this).text(),
                showCurrentLi = currentLiText.indexOf(searchText) !== -1;

            $(this).toggle(showCurrentLi);

        });     
    });

});
```

Is there any way to optimize it?

Here's a link: http://jsfiddle.net/EFTZR/897/

Comment: `currentLiText.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) !== -1;`

Comment: You could also read "String searching alorithm" if you really want to make a kick ass search engine: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Comment: Thanks Myster X, it works perfectly!

Comment: What do you want when you say "optimize it"? I add some visual feedback in my anwser for example, is this an optimization for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the items to `lowerCase` before comparing like this

```js
$(function() {

  $('input.search').keyup(function() {

    var searchText = $(this).val();

    $('ul.tabs-menu > li').each(function() {

      var currentLiText = $(this).text(),
        showCurrentLi = currentLiText.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) !== -1;

      $(this).toggle(showCurrentLi);

    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="search" />

<ul class="tabs-menu" id="category1">
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="tabs-menu">
  <li>item27</li>
  <li>item28</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I add some visual feedback to see what you are looking for in your list (with the same code as the other anwser for the searching function) and change your item list to see it better.

```js
$(function() {

  $('input.search').keyup(function() {

    var searchText = $(this).val().trim();

    $('ul.tabs-menu > li').each(function() {

      var currentLiText = $(this).text(),
        showCurrentLi = currentLiText.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) !== -1;

      $(this).toggle(showCurrentLi);
      $(this).html(currentLiText.replace(searchText, "<span class='bold'>" + searchText + "</span>"))

    });
  });

});
```

```css
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="search" />

<ul class="tabs-menu" id="category1">
  <li>first item</li>
  <li>second item</li>
  <li>one more item</li>
</ul>
<ul class="tabs-menu">
  <li>item test</li>
  <li>check item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clean and optimized way to do that ( It is case-insensitive ):

```
$(function(){
    var timer;

    function search( searchText ) {
        $('ul.tabs-menu > li').each(function(){

            var $this = $(this),
                currentLiText = $this.text().trim().toLowerCase(),
                showCurrentLi = currentLiText.indexOf( searchText ) !== -1;

            $this.toggle( showCurrentLi );

        });
    }

    $('input.search').keyup(function(){
        var searchText = $(this).val().trim().toLowerCase();
        // Checks the value of searchText.
        if (searchText) {
            // Clears the timer.
            if ( timer ){
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }
            // Gives the user 1 second to finish typing.
            timer = setTimeout( search.bind(this, searchText ), 1000 ); 

        }

    });  
});
```

I hope you like it : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EFTZR/921/)